# HiveContext singleton object

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a streaming app and when i try invoking the HiveContext.getOrCreate, it errors out with the following stmt. '**object HiveContext in package hive cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.sql.hive**'

I would require HiveContext instead of SQLContext for my application and creating new HiveContext everytime would not be a feasible solution.

Here is my code snippet:

```
object sampleStreamingApp  {

  def createStreamingContext(checkpointDirectory: String): StreamingContext = {
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sampleStreaming")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Milliseconds(5000))
   ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)
   val smDStream = ssc.textFileStream("/user/hdpuser/data")
   val smSplitted = smDStream.map( x => x.split(";") ).map( x => Row.fromSeq( x ) )
   smSplitted.foreachRDD { rdd =>
             val sqlContext = HiveContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
            import sqlContext.implicits._ 
            <other code logic goes here>
      }
   }
   ssc
}

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val checkpointDirectory = "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/dfml/checkpointing/AAA"
   val ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, () => createStreamingContext(checkpointDirectory))

   ssc.start()
   ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The object HiveContext is private, hence its not accessible.